# How to resolve td data not being mapped using .map()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using the ASP Razor syntax to construct a table. Then I pass down each `td` value for a row when a button on that row is clicked.

But during testing I notice that data in `td` at index `3` and `4` are not mapped. While elements below that index are mapped successfully.

The only difference I can see that may be messing up the map is that, on index 3 the elements is a `@Html.TextArea` and on index 4 the element is a nested `input` of type date.

How can you resolve td values not being mapped with `map()`?

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var row in Model.Status)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Raw(row.ID)</td>
            <td>@Html.Raw(row.Email)</td>
            <td>@row.RID</td>
            <td>@Html.TextArea("@row.Notes", new { @class = "form-control-sm", rows = 5, style = "width: 300px" })</td>
            <td><input type="date"  value="@row.Date"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

```js
$(".btn-success").click(function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children("td"),
    len = $td.length;
    var tableData = $td.map(function (i) {
        if (i < len - 1)
            return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log(tableData);
    alert(tableData)

    tableData = {
        ID: tableData[0],
        Email: tableData[1],
        RID: tableData[2],
        Notes: tableData[3],
        Date: tableData[4]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `text()` method only gets the contents of text nodes within the specified `td`. `textarea` and `input` elements are separate to that logic and so their values are ignored.

To solve this you need to check if the current `td` contains a form element and return it's `value` to `map()` instead. Try this:

```
var tableData = $td.not(':last').map(function(i) {
    return $(this).find(':input').length ? $(this).find(':input').val() : $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Working example:

```js
$('.btn-success').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  var tableData = $td.not(':last').map(function(i) {
    return $(this).find(':input').length ? $(this).find(':input').val() : $(this).text();
  }).get();

  console.log(tableData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>RowId1</td>
      <td>Email1</td>
      <td>RID1</td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control-sm" rows="5" style="width: 300px">Notes1</textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" value="2016-09-01">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok makes sense, although there is a syntax error on the end of the return?  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Comment: @BrianJ Apologies, it was a syntax error in the ternary. I've updated the answer

Comment: see that now, seems to be a flaw in logic though. This implementation only returns the td vals with a nested input. Doesn't return the rest of the normal td's vals without nested inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: So find any inputs, if an input get the val. Else get the text of a non input. nice.

Comment: That's it exactly :)